# Find positive subunitary solution

Tags: calculus

I have this function

$$ f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R,\space \space f(x) = x^{13}+x^7+x-1  $$
And i need to prove that there is only ONE positive, smaller than 1 root for the ecuation. This problem is categorised at Rolle's Theorem. I know the theorem, but I don't know how to correctly apply it.

Comment: By Descartes rule of signs, there is only one positive root. I think there are proofs of Descartes rule using Rolle's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: $f(x)$ is continuous in $(0,1)$ and differentiable in $[0,1]$. Also $f(0)<0$ and $f(1)>0$. So what can you conclude about $f(x)=0$? Where will $x$ lie to satisfy $f(x)=0$?